# How to get the next task in a REST API request using postman?

Tags: api, postman, rest

Lets say I have a REST API get request like this one that query the task_id=101:

```
GET  http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/queries/tasks/instances/process/101
```

And I want to query task_id=102, but without putting 102 in the URL manually, but have something like this in the URL:

```
GET  http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/queries/tasks/instances/process/101+1
```

I tried this and it wont work. So, what I actually want is to add somehow that +1 not to put 102 manually there?

Comment: Well, with javascript this would be a one liner... but you're not saying you're using javascript. Are you trying to code this inside postman?

Comment: Maybe I can put a body inside postman with JavaScript?

Comment: @Evert how can I solve this with JavaScript in the body of a postman request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change you url to :

http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/queries/tasks/instances/process/{{id}}

now we are referring to id variable instead of hard coding it. now modify it from the pre-request script as: **just add this to pre-request script**

```
pm.environment.get("id") ? pm.environment.set("id",pm.environment.get("id")+1) : pm.environment.set("id",101)

//pm.environment.unset("id")
```

now for each request send the id will get incremented . if you want to reset it to 101 just send one request with   pm.environment.unset("id") uncommented and then comment it back

Answer (score 0):

You could use environment variables and fulfill those automatically when you get a response from the first request.

Take a look at this doc: https://blog.postman.com/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/

Comment: hi @thiago, the first request doesn't have any data inside. That's why I'm trying to request the second one using +1.

Comment: So I think you can create an environment variable with the first number you need. And then, in the tests tab of each request just add +1 to that environment variable.